# Originalvalue in RowDeleted-Event

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I have the following Code:

```
public Test() {
    var dt = new DataTable("arguments");
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");

    dt.RowDeleted += DtOnRowDeleted;

    dt.Rows[0].Delete();
}

private void DtOnRowDeleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
    var id = e.Row["id", DataRowVersion.Original];
}
```

The Problem is, that I get a `VersionNotFoundException` when try to read the originalvalue in the Eventhandler:

```
var id = e.Row["id", DataRowVersion.Original];
```

How can I get the id from the deleted datarow?

Comment: Is this the real code? You will never be called on a row that is not in the Unchanged state

Comment: its only sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method after your table is set.

```
dt.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c");
dt.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
dt.AcceptChanges();
dt.RowDeleted += DtOnRowDeleted;
```